# After mounting new hard drive, Ubuntu won't boot, only presents grey screen

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

I reformatted a 1TB drive to ext4 instead of NFTS yesterday. However, suddenly today, Ubuntu refuses to boot for me.

I use Grub 2 to be able to boot both Windows 10(on it's own SSD drive) and Ubuntu 17.04 Gnome(on it's own SSD drive).

I am suspecting the 1TB ext4 drive might be dirty. Could it be?

What I don't understand is this: I have no access to the terminal. Upon booting Ubuntu, the monitor simply goes grey; no text, and `CTRL+ALT+F1` does nothing. I have no idea where to start when I don't even have terminal access.

I've tried cleaning from the grub menu recovery mode to no luck.

What can I do to save my Ubuntu partition? [image]

Comment: How can I check /etc/fstab if I have no access to the terminal?

Comment: I have ubuntu on a USB stick, yes.

Comment: @ravery i managed to go in recovery mode and get the terminal, I uploaded a picture of the output. Appreciate the help.

Comment: The UID is indeed the same. How to I change it?

Comment: So just change ntfs-3g to ext4 ?

Comment: Hallelujah, I am in. Thank you sir. Feel free to answer and I'll accept. Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70462/discussion-between-cbll-and-ravery).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data drive is automonted, so it is hanging because the fstab entry in now incorrect.

From the recovery mode terminal type:

```
nano /etc/fstab
```

Edit the entry for the data drive. If you only formatted then the UUID should be the same but verify. You need to change the file type to `ext4` and change the options to `defaults`. the result should look like:

```
UUID=<the ID> /path/for/mount ext4 defaults 0 0
```

save and reboot.